# cannot access/delete folder in Rubbish Bin containing hundred of thousand of corrupted files on 14.04

Tags: nautilus, files, directory, trash, rm

yesterday I discovered a folder in the **Trash Bin** named **`FdtN0bhKRX`** containing more than 700,000 corrupted files. I know the approximate number because I tried to move the folder to a USB key, and when I cancelled the operation, the "preparing to move.." dialogue was showing that mark. The folder is 1017Mb and the files inside are all 0 byte long.
I tried everything I could to remove this folder or to access it, but I failed. **`sudo rm`** or **`sudo su`** and then **`rm`** with `-d` and `-f` options goes in infinite loop, which may cause a complete block of the  system's functions (including **`Ctrl+Alt+Del`**). I even coded a c++ program, which works great on other folders, but in this case it failed miserably. I searched all over the web and I couldn't find any other case like my one. The files inside the folder are named something like this:

`S                             __FrO__                         kj`

I could read some of the names one of the times I tried to open the folder in Nautilus, because before the program crashed, if I clicked the back button, some of the files icons were rendered together with their name. The only command I can use on the folder is **`mv`** AFIK.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem with the monstrous folder which was by me found in the Trash folder. Nor the folder, nor its files had been corrupted, indeed it was a `HDD Bad Blocks` problem, which I detected with **`fsck`**, by running it from another partition. I'm not expert on Hard Drive, but I can say that **`fsck`** detected a problem in the folder structure (probably where the Trash folder reside on the disk).

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
sudo rm -rf path-to-the-folder
```

if didn't work, do it with `root` privileges type `sudo su` press Enter and repeat the command no `sudo` required.

**WARNING!**

When login as a `root`, do it at your own risk! If you completely sure this folder is nothing then ok.

Comment: I didn't mention it because I thought it had been obvious, but I have used **rm** as root, too. Thanks for sharing, anyway.